# Matching on a enum String

Tags: rust, enums

I am learning Rust and I am trying to write a simple IP handling function

```
enum IpAddr{
   v4(u8,u8,u8,u8),
   v6(String),
}

impl IpAddr{
    fn write(&self){
        match *self {
            IpAddr::v4(A,B,C,D) => println!("{}.{}.{}.{}",A,B,C,D),
            IpAddr::v6(S) => println!("{}",S) 
        }
    }
}
```

The v4 matches fine, but I get the following build error on the 2nd one

> error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.0` which is behind a shared reference

> move occurs because `_S` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

How can I match on a enum with a String attached?

Comment: FYI, you aren't following the [Rust naming conventions](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html) (which should be generating a bunch of warnings, by default).

Answer (score 3):

Its complaining because you are trying to copy `self` by dereferencing, but `IpAddr` contains a `String` which is not copy-able.

Remove the dereference and it should work as expected

```
match self {
    IpAddr::v4(A,B,C,D) => println!("{}.{}.{}.{}",A,B,C,D),
    IpAddr::v6(S) => println!("{}",S) 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're matching on `*self`, as it [does not appear to be necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467483/574531), but if you really need to do that for some reason, you can also solve the problem by using the [`ref` keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.ref.html) with your variable (`ref s`), which will cause the value to be borrowed instead of moving it.

```rust
enum IpAddr{
   V4(u8,u8,u8,u8),
   V6(String),
}

impl IpAddr{
    fn write(&self){
        match *self {
            IpAddr::V4(a,b,c,d) => println!("{}.{}.{}.{}",a,b,c,d),
            IpAddr::V6(ref s) => println!("{}", s) 
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d49c294577fd21045cc1aa19fe4bb82)